# Bayes classification in matlab histogram?

Tags: matlab, histogram, bayesian

I have 2 variable pat and target.Pat variable consist of 2 row and 500 columns.Target variable 1*500.
pat variable contains 500 patterns coded as 2D feature vectors x = [x1 x2]T . The second variable(target) is a vector of 500 labels assigning the patterns to one of two classes, w0 or w1

I want to use bayes classification rule in matlab.Like that x1|w0, x1|w1 and x2|w0, x2|w1.
x1 and x2 related to pat variable
w0 and w1 related to target variable.
I want to show x1|w0, x1|w1 and x2|w0, x2|w1 with hist command.
How can I show bayes rule in matlab with histogram ?
Is there any possible normalize the histograms to range from 0 to 1 ?

Comment: don't be discouraged by the vote downs. Could you explain more clearly what you have tried?

Comment: I'm not sure how to compute what you want to show, but once you have the values perhaps `bar` would help you display them?  Also, can you just divide by the maximum element to normalize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
clear all; close all; clc;
format compact

pat=rand(2,500); %500 samples with 2 features each
target=rand(1,500)>0.5; %w0 and w1 assignments

edges=[0:0.1:1];
pat1_w0=histc(pat(1,target==0),edges); %x1|w0
pat1_w0=pat1_w0/sum(pat1_w0); %normalize

pat2_w0=histc(pat(2,target==0),edges); %x2|w0
pat2_w0=pat2_w0/sum(pat1_w0); %normalize

pat1_w1=histc(pat(1,target==1),edges); %x1|w1
pat1_w1=pat1_w1/sum(pat1_w0); %normalize

pat2_w1=histc(pat(2,target==1),edges); %x2|w1
pat2_w1=pat2_w1/sum(pat1_w0); %normalize

figure
hold on
bar(pat1_w0,'r') %insert whatever variable here to graph
bar(pat2_w0,'g')
bar(pat1_w1,'b')
bar(pat2_w1,'y')
```